# "vertical viewpoint was given unbounded height" error in slivers (flutter)

Tags: flutter

I am trying to integrate Streambuilder that contains user ratings of a shop into a sliver format. but I am encountering an unbounded height error. Below is the code for the shop details that contain the user's ratings.

```
class _ShopDetailState extends State<ShopDetail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Storage storage = Storage();
    
    //user
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

    //text controller
    final textController = TextEditingController();

    //post function
    void post(){...

     return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          
          //sliver app bar
          SliverAppBar.medium(...
          
          //user ratings
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("${widget.shop.name} Ratings")
                        .orderBy(
                          "TimeStamp",
                          descending: false,
                        )
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            //get message
                            final post = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                            return UserShopRating(
                              type: widget.shop.name,
                              msg: post['Rating'],
                              user: post['UserEmail'],
                              postId: post.id,                          
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Text('Error:${snapshot.error}'),
                        );
                      }
                      return const Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Below is my code for a user's rating.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 15, right: 15),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [

          //rating
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                //(message + user email)
                Column(
                  children: [
                    //message
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text(widget.msg),
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(height: 5),
                    //email
                    SizedBox(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text(
                        widget.user,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                      ),
                    ),

                    const SizedBox(height: 8),

                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, 
                      children: [
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    
                      const Spacer(),
                      if (widget.user == user.email)
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            DeleteButton(onTap: deletePost),
                            const SizedBox(width: 5),
                            const Text('Delete Rating'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ]
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried setting "shrinkWrap : true" and wrapping the ListView in Expanded but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are putting a scrollable widget into another scrollable widget(a SingleChildScrollView of UserRating child widget into a ListView parent), that's where is problem is from.

Try to give the column with SingleChildScrollView in the UserRating widget an explict height.